# Conditionally insert from one table into another

Tags: postgresql

The same name may appear in multiple rows of *table1*. I would like to enumerate all names in sequential order 1, 2, ... One way to do so is to

1. create new table with `name` as primary key and `id` as `serial` type.
2. Select `name` from `table1` and insert it into `table2` only when it doesn't exist

```
table1 (name vchar(50), ...)

table2 (name vchar(50) primary key, id serial)


insert into table2(name)
select name
from table1 limit 9
where not exists (select name from table2 where name = table1.name)
```

This doesn't work. How to fix it?

Comment: `limit` needs to go **after** the `where` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select distinct values:

```
insert into table2(name)
select distinct name
from table1
order by name;
```